# Is there an easy way to reset user permissions back to usergroup settings?

Tags: permissions

Is it a matter of clearing the userpermissions_users table?

Background: After initial authoring, we've cleaned up permissions for our usergroups, but the existing users have accumulated manually-added permissions as sections got added.  Would be nice to be able to blanket-remove all the custom permissions.
(Also, "Deselect All" in the User Settings' Permissions tab is doing a select-all instead.)
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that turning on Admin (and saving) and then turning it off will reset the user's permissions to their group defaults.  It's not the fastest, but faster than going through all the checkboxes.